# PgBadger report from AWS RDS log parsed not fully

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgbadger

I use pgbadger as following:

```
pgbadger -p %t:%r:%u@%d:[%p]: postgresql.log
```

log_line_prefix are set for RDS and cannot be changed. Its same that i pass to pgbadger ( %t:%r:%u@%d:[%p]: )

When i launch pgbadger i get following stdout output.

```
[=======================> ] Parsed 52063631 bytes of 52063634 (100.00%), queries: 66116, events: 0
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
```

So it parsed queries, and it output i see most of stats. But in Top section i see wrong info. Time consuming queries and  Slowest individual queries says "no dataset". And in Most frequent queries (N) all queries have all durations as 0 . See screenshot here : http://clip2net.com/s/3wUxfXg . And examples for query dont show any examples at all.
I checked postgresql log and duration is there. For example:

```
2016-04-13 22:00:02 UTC:blabla.com(43372):blabla@blabla:[20584]:LOG:  statement: SELECT DISTINCT "reports2_report"."id", "reports2_report"."created", "reports2_report"."modified", "reports2_report"."data", "reports2_report"."person_info", "reports2_report"."status", "reports2_report"."source_profile_id", "reports2_report"."application_id", "reports2_report"."error_detail" FROM "reports2_report" INNER JOIN "reports2_reportsourceprofile" ON ( "reports2_report"."source_profile_id" = "reports2_reportsourceprofile"."id" ) INNER JOIN "reports2_reportsource" ON ( "reports2_reportsourceprofile"."report_source_id" = "reports2_reportsource"."id" ) INNER JOIN "applications_applicationdocument" ON ( "reports2_report"."application_id" = "applications_applicationdocument"."slug" ) WHERE ("reports2_reportsource"."identifier" = 'redridge_credit' AND "reports2_report"."application_id" = 'jqLoMe' AND ("reports2_report"."application_id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT V0."slug" FROM "applications_applicationdocument" V0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "auth_user" V1 ON ( V0."seller_id" = V1."id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts_companymembership" V2 ON ( V1."id" = V2."user_id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN "applications_applicationbundle" V5 ON ( V0."bundle_id" = V5."id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN "applications_applicationbundle_sharees" V6 ON ( V5."id" = V6."applicationbundle_id" ) WHERE (V2."company_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "accounts_company" U0 WHERE (U0."lft" > 2 AND U0."tree_id" = 6 AND U0."rght" < 3)) OR V0."applicant_id" = 111827 OR V0."seller_id" = 111827 OR V6."user_id" = 111827)) OR "applications_applicationdocument"."seller_id" = 111827 OR "applications_applicationdocument"."applicant_id" = 111827 OR "reports2_reportsourceprofile"."user_id" = 111827)) ORDER BY "reports2_report"."created" DESC LIMIT 20
2016-04-13 22:00:02 UTC:blabla.com(43372):blabla@blabla:[20584]:LOG:  duration: 517.047 ms
```

How to get PgBadger to generate full proper report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to log_statement = all instead of log_statement=none. log_min_duration_statement  works only if log_statement = none